# How to implement semi-random groups with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

suppose I've got groups:

```
{1=>[1,1,1,1,1,1], 2=>[2,2,2], 3=>[3,3,3,3,3,3], 4=>[4,4,4,4,4,4]}
```

the keys represent teams, and the values within the arrays represent employees. Imagine I wish to match employees in a semi-random way. I want to make groups of 3's-5's like this:

```
[1,1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,3], [1,3,4,1,4]
```

I have the wish to create groups and have a bias for matching team members of opposite teams, but not an absolute bias. Also you must match every member of each team with a group.

How would you solve this?

This is how I've done it:

```
group_by_team = records.group_by {|x| x.team_id}.values
mixed_groups = group_by_team.each{|x| x.shuffle!}

# take 1 element from each team and mix
# the number of teams is defined as a constant so we don't have to hit the db with a count
for index in (1..(TEAMS-1))
  zipped_groups ||= mixed_groups[0]
  zipped_groups = zipped_groups.zip(mixed_groups[index])
end 

# flatten the arrays to produce one large Array
# remove nil values from ziped steps with compact!
zipped_groups = zipped_groups.flatten!.compact!
lunch_groups = zipped_groups.each_slice(3)


# we can no longer reduce table size, so lets join two small lunch groups
if lunch_groups.any?{|x| x.size<3}
  lunch_groups = self.merge_last_two(lunch_groups)
end
```

But the problems with my implementation are vast. Groups size is fixed at 3. And its no exactly elegant, or efficient.

**How would you make semi-random groups happen?**

Comment: If you tell us the grouping criteria we might be able to suggest how you could optimize a measure of the criteria, but don't expect to get help with the criteria and measures of the criteria--that's your job.

Comment: The criteria is listed above "a bias for matching team members of opposite teams". 

This was an interview question. I have an answer above that solves for match members of opposite teams, but the feedback I received was it was implemented in a a poor way. Hence the stack-overflow curiosity

Comment: If you dig into the question, it is in fact interesting. I know no way to implement semi-random. I'm looking for a matching algorithm

Comment: example outputs are also listed:

[1,1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,3], [1,3,4,1,4]

Comment: "a bias for matching team members of opposite teams" is not a criterion, it is only a notion for what is wanted. Your criteria must be *measurable*. An example of a criterion (to be maximized) is the minimum of the number of groups represented in each of the arrays produced (which, incidentally, would be a difficult problem). Moreover, I don't know what you mean by "semi-random".

Comment: Its was interview question! chill out!

Comment: Semi-random: do not match members of the same groups (see hash) 75% of the time.